# SQL Server Full Text Search with nordic characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I'm trying to make full text search work with my application, but have run into an issue I have no idea how to fix.

Take this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Books
WHERE CONTAINS(([Description], ReverseDescription), '"øgle"')
```

Øgle is the danish word for lizzard, for those who are wondering. This query gives 37 results, that makes perfect sense, you would think.

Now, take this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Books
WHERE CONTAINS(([Description], ReverseDescription), '"ogle"')
```

It gives the exact same 37 results. Why is that? It seems like no matter which of the characters 'o' or 'ø' I search for, it finds both. This hold true for 'æ' and 'a' aswell.

Anyone who can shed some light on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Full Text Search matches part of a word, even without wildcard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586610/sql-server-full-text-search-matches-part-of-a-word-even-without-wildcard)

Comment: @ChrisPickford The two questions represent two different issues, I would say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling accent sensitivity solved the problem.
This can be done like so:

```
ALTER FULLTEXT CATALOG "your_fulltext_catalog"
REBUILD WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = ON;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS

for example query will look like

```
SELECT * FROM Books
   WHERE CONTAINS(([Description], ReverseDescription), '"øgle*"')
 AND [Description] COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS LIKE '%"øgle*"%'
```